# Centering Inner Circular Div in CSS3

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [this CSS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2Wkqn/2/) and let me know how I can center the inner div inside the outter div and also center the text for inner div?

```
.outer{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fc2e5a;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.inner {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the `table-cell` or [`flex-box`](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/) or `position` if you know the exact sizes of your divs then you could do something like this:

```
.outer{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fc2e5a;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
       box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wkqn/4/)

Notice that I removed the browser specific prefixes for `border-radius` and also set it to `50%` to make it independent from the whole size.

Comment: Notice that I removed the border-radius browser specific prefixes as they already supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wkqn/5/

Add the lines

```
position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
```

to your .inner CSS

Wrap your text "Test" in paragraph tags then add a class ".inner p" to your CSS and enter the lines:

```
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
```